# How to download videos from private chats on telegram?

Tags: web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, telegram, telegram-bot, developer-tools

Preferably with using developeer tools, finding the network element, get the request URL, and download the video from there?

The problem is that when I try to do that, and press download, the video is not saved correctly, and the video file is corrupt?